# trigger a function in flatlist when user swipes right the last page react native

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I want to apply a functionality so that when user swipe the last page (end of chapter )of flatlist
next chapter loads in flatlist and previous one gets removed .

their is a function which triggers as soon as user reaches the last of flatlist (last page) but i want to trigger when user swipe the last page it self to right

```
<FlatList
  style={{ width: contentWidth }}
  ref={flatListRef}  
  windowSize={10}
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  data={selectedChapter ? [selectedChapter] :  []} 
  keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()} 
  onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => {console.log("sada")}}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  renderItem={({ item }) => renderContentPages(item)}
  onViewableItemsChanged={(info) => {alert(info.viewableItems[0].index)}}
  
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague, however if I understand it correctly, you are looking for some kind of gesture handling behavior which is not implemented on FlatList by default.
So your solution should be a little bit different. You should render all your array using FlatList except the last one, and then render the last component separately and wrap it with . Then, add your desired swipe right functionality to that.
Something like this:

```
<FlatList
 style={{ width: contentWidth }}
 ref={flatListRef}  
 windowSize={10}
 horizontal
 pagingEnabled
 removeClippedSubviews={true}
 // data={all items except the last one} last item should be removed from the list to render it deparately
 keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()} 
 onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => {console.log("sada")}}
 showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
 renderItem={({ item }) => renderContentPages(item)}
 onViewableItemsChanged={(info) => {alert(info.viewableItems[0].index)}}
/>

<PanGestureHandler 
// add swipe right functionality here
>
  {renderContentPages(lastItem)}
<PanGestureHandler>
```

I hope this helps, and If I have not got your question right, please provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for response. Data coming from api is array of objects of chapters. I'm slicing and showing 1 chapter at a time in flatlist. When user reach the end of chapter and again swipe right then I want to trigger a function that will show new chapter in flatlist

Comment: Due to large data I can't render all chapters at once

Comment: 1 chapter is further divided in pages. Those pages number can vary as changes of font size also implemented (reading screen it is)